# Calculate $(i+u_0)(i+u_1)\cdots(i+u_{n-1})$ if $u_0,u_1,...u_{n-1}$ are $n-$th roots of unity

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, complex-numbers, products, roots-of-unity

Let $u_0,u_1,...u_{n-1}$ be all complex $n-$th roots of unity.

Calculate the product:
$$(i+u_0)(i+u_1)\cdots(i+u_{n-1})$$
I've tried various tricks, like $i = e^{i\frac{1}{2}\pi}$, $u_k=e^{ik\frac{2}{n}\pi}$. Also tried to evaluate the product as a polynomial, but I'm not sure if it yields anything.

Comment: *Hint:* $z^n-1= (z-u_0)(z-u_1)\cdots (z-u_n)$. Now substitute a suitable value for $z$.

Comment: That was the key...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that, if $u_0,\ldots,u_{n-1}$ are roots of unity, then
$$
x^n-1=\prod_{j=0}^{n-1}(x-u_j)
$$
hence for $x=-i$, we obtain
$$
(-i)^n-1=\prod_{j=0}^{n-1}(-i-u_j)=(-1^n)\prod_{j=0}^{n-1}(i+u_j)
$$
and thus
$$
\prod_{j=0}^{n-1}(i+u_j)=(-1)^n\big((-i)^n-1\big)=i^n-(-1)^n.
$$